# openerp gtk client 6.1 - form tab label

Tags: windows, gtk, client, odoo

In the new openERP gtk client 6.1, a new feature is causing confusing at times. the **tab label** of a certain record in **form view** is now as such:

`Object: (Id, Name)`

instead of the good 'ol

`Object`

Sometimes it just adds the name of the record and not both name and id, depends on the object's name whether it's a many2one field or not.
Ive been trying to pinpoint where in the new gtk client code is this added but i cant find it. i think it's in /bin/widget/view/form_gtk but im not sure.

another thing, once you good people tell me where the new code is added it's easy to modify the client on linux based OS, but how about patching the client on windows instead of building a new exe installer? i would very much appreciate it if someone could share some insight about this matter. I've already seen this [Create exe open erp client GTK](https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp/openerp/win-installer-trunk) on launchpad, but when i followed it step by step on XP, i encountered errors. i think it's outdated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that a bug report + a question?

Comment: it's not a bug, the new labeling is a new functionality that i need to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

In the project lp:openerp-tools you will find the solution. There is the official script with the .exe is created.

BTW, you dont need to recreate the .exe, you can run python on windows as an script (exactly as in Linux does, I don give support for windows never, but i know in end clients it is frequent problem.

Regards, and i hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks Nhomar, i managed to run the client directly on windows, and also create a new installer using the nightly builds where the python dependencies are updated. however, do u mean there is a solution in lp:openerp-tools for the original question i asked? the form label i mean?

Answer (score 0):

Noup..

In openerp-tools where the tools to build the .exe, not the tag problem, this is really easy if you know a little of python + gtk.

But BTW it should be cool if you post the solution you found for future people that need something like you...

Regards.

Comment: I updated your answer to include the solution i found. i had already stated that it can be achieved using the openerp nightly builds, but added the link to be more clear. Please remove this as an answer and use comments instead :). Thanks!